# how do i load data from parser using (from parser import load_data)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

### how do i load data from parser using (from parser import load_data)

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)

in ()

```
 13 import numpy as np #math

 14
```

---> 15 from parser import load_data #data loading

```
 16
```

ImportError: cannot import name 'load_data'

i am working on image classification and creating my own classifier and i am not getting the solution for this error. i am using python anaconda 3 and tensor flow framework for my project and all the packages are installed including:
keras
tensor flow
ipython

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXRUr.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXRUr.jpg)

Comment: import keras #ml
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation
#from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

#from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
#from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
#from keras import backend as K
#import parser
#from Parsers import parser
#from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Conv2D, Model
import numpy as np #math

from parser import load_data #data loading

Comment: I was looking the Siraj videos and I have the same problem is import that on the video but when I try the same I have error like you

Comment: Try to use Keras instead.

from keras.datasets import imdb
train_data=imdb.load_data('yourdatapath')

Answer (score 1):

The python module `parser` doesn't contain a function or class called `load_data`.

Here are the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/parser.html) I don't think this is the module that you have intended to use.

Comment: if parser doesn't contain any load data variable then what library should i use to load may data set.

Comment: What is the structure of your data?

Comment: import keras #ml 
from keras.models import Sequential
import numpy as np #math
from parser import load_data #data loading

#1
training_data=load_data('adas')
validation_data=load_data('adas')
#2
model=sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(32,3,3 ))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

Comment: i am using tensorflow and for my dataset i need library